# Proxy + Webdriver

Tags: python, proxy

Всем привет. Не работает эта строчка : `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)`

Код :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

def proxy(pr , PROXY):  
    if pr == False:
        pass
    elif pr == True:
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)  # <---

def main():
    ...
```

Никакой ошибки не выдает, просто работает через мой IP.

Comment: PROXY имеет правильный формат протокол://хост:порт ?

Comment: Прокси имеет такой вид: 102.129.249.120:8080, раньше все так работало, а если нет, то выдавало ошибку, сейчас попробую так : протокол://хост:порт

Comment: Попробовал так : http:// 102.129.249.120:8080, результат тот же

Comment: А, так вы ж меняете опции уже после того, как они были использованы. Нужно сперва делать options.add_argument, а уже потом создавать webdriver.Chrome, иначе опции просто опоздают и не применятся

Comment: Поднял функцию proxy прямо под import BeautifulSoupa, результат не изменился. Такое ощущение что это из-за самой функции, потому что options.add_argument('headless') работает

Comment: Важно не расположение функции, а момент её вызова. Вызываете-то вы её видимо всё равно после webdriver.Chrome, так что ничего не изменилось

Comment: Точно, только я не совсем понимаю как можно загружать эту функцию быстрее webdriver, дело в том что у меня еще подключен gui на pyqt5, и когда я жму запуск, в любом случае сперва подгружается webdriver

Comment: Оставьте его неинициализированным `browser = None`, а где-нибудь в main или в другом месте после вызова proxy уже инициализируйте `global browser; browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`

Comment: Попробовал в main, не получилось, видимо main вызывается первее чем proxy, а если вставить это в proxy, то ругается на эту строку в main: browser.get(url) , говорит - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. Есть ли какой-то способ контролировать что будет загружаться первее? Просто я не до конца понимаю моменты вызовов функции, и не могу точно говорить что в какой момент вызывается

Comment: Проблема в том что функция proxy вызывается в момент нажатия единственной кнопки gui, а собственно кроме нажатия этой кнопки там больше нечего делать, получается нужно вызывать функцию до нажатия кнопки, а кнопок больше нет. Конечно есть вариант добавить отдельную кнопку типа: 'Установить Прокси' Но это нежелательно

Comment: Не пойму в чем проблема поставить `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)` на следущей строке, после `options.add_argument('headless')` ? Ведь по сути это самый правильный вариант

Comment: Мне надо передавать значение PROXY в другой модуль, и я не знаю как это можно сделать без функции, по этому использую отдельную функцию.